# Hibernate criteria query to display children

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to develop a currently very simple web application using Hibernate for the data portion.  Basically, I am attempting to get a table with a row for each category.  In one cell for each row, I want to display the KPIs for that category. To do that, I am attempting to use a criteria object. The immediate problem is that nothing I can do results in that second query even firing.

Here are the hopefully relevant bits from my code. I've tried all sorts of things, this is what I've currently got.

**Category.java**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @Column(name="category_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @Transient
    private Kpi[] kpis;
...
    public Kpi[] getKpis() {
        return this.kpis;
    }
}
```

**CategoryDAO**

```
public interface CategoryDAO {

    public List<Category> listCategories();
    public Category getCategoryById(int id);
    public List<Kpi> getKpisForCategory(int cat);
}
```

**CategoryDAOImpl**

```
public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

...
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Kpi> getKpisForCategory(int cat) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Kpi.class).add(Restrictions.eq("category_id",cat));
        return criteria.list();
    }
}
```

**CategoryServiceImpl**

```
 @Service
    public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

        private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;

        public void setCategoryDAO(CategoryDAO dao) {
            this.categoryDAO = dao;
        }
...    
        @Override
        public List<Kpi> listKpisForCategory(int cat) {
            System.out.println("in service method");
            return this.categoryDAO.getKpisForCategory(cat);
        }
    }
```

**jsp**

```
<c:if test="${!empty listCategories}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">Category ID</th>
            <th width="120">Category Name</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listCategories}" var="category">
        <tr>
            <td>${category.id}</td>
            <td>${category.categoryName}</td>
            <td>
                <table class="tg">
                    <tr>
                        <th>KPI Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                    <c:forEach items="${category.kpis }" var="kpi">
                        <td>${category.id}
                        <td>${kpi.kpiName }</td>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>    
</c:if>
```

No matter what I do, I end up with the nested table being empty, and the child query never fires (which I can tell due to my high tech logging!).  What am I missing?
(sorry for the wall of text...)

Comment: You never show where the `List<Kpi>` ever gets assigned to your `Category`.

Comment: @Naros, I don't know how I would do that, which may be the whole of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Naros's comment, I was able to get it working. In the CategoryDAOImpl class, I added some code to the listCategories() method to populate the Kpi list in the Category object:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Category> listCategories() {
        System.out.println("dao impl list categories");
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Category> categoryList = session.createQuery("from Category").list();

        for (Category c : categoryList) {
            List<Kpi> kpiList = getKpisForCategory(c.getId());
            c.setKpis(kpiList);
        }
        return categoryList;
    }
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Be sure to mark this as the answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Your Kpi class should have a reference to category field (let's name it "category"). Then your DAO should create references Criteria for the category and add your restriction there.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Kpi.class);
Criteria categoryCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("category");
categoryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",cat));
return criteria.list();
```

Or you can try `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("category.id",cat));`